# ruby on rails friendship following shows always my name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, friend

**friendship.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, :include => [:profile]
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'user'
```

**user.rb**

```
  #following code
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

  #followers code
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

using this code to display who i have friended and who has friended me

**view**

```
   <h2>Friends</h2>
    <ul>
      <% for friendship in @user.friendships.includes(:user) %>
        <li>
          <%= friendship.user.username %>
          (<%= link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete %>)
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <p><%= link_to "Find Friends", users_path %></p>

    <h2>Friended by Users</h2>
    <ul>
      <% for user in @user.inverse_friends %>
        <li><%=h user.username %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

on the first loop block i always get my username printed, lets call it "**fxuser**"
on the second loop block i get the correct usernames of who have friended me...

how can this be solved so the first loop will display the correct usernames of who i have friended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first loop I believe `friendship.user` is referring back to yourself; you're looking for the `friendship.friend`. Also, I think you want to be removing the `friendship`, not the inverse in the delete link.

```
 <% for friendship in @user.friendships.includes(:friend) %>
    <li>
      <%= friendship.friend.username %>
      (<%= link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete %>)
    </li>
 <% end %>
```

You also need to change

```
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'user'
```

to

```
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
```